# how can i get the sum of all the products in a certain month in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, oop

i am trying to get all the sum of payments made in a specific month lets say from January - March in my website .
My table which is equipments has Money and Joined as columns but the Joined column has both date and time .
I want to use this approach if it is possible but this snippet is for sum of prize.

if (isset($_POST['moneyMade'])){
    $moneyMade=0;

```
$query = "select SUM(Money) from users where Joined<='2016-11-01 00:00:00' and Joined>='2016-11-31 00:00:00'";
//if (!$query) { echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error(); exit; }
//$query="select * from equipments ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);



while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  /*  Fetch a result row as an associative array */
 /*while ($row = mysqli_result($result)){*/
  $moneyMade +=$row['Money'];


}

echo "Money made for this month is ". $moneyMade;

  }
```

How can i achieve this using php and some sql ? 
Thank you.

Comment: show your query or what you have done already

Comment: Share some dummy data & your attempted query?

Comment: try something like this `select SUM(amt) from tab_name where `DateTime`<='2016-11-01 00:00:00' and DateTime>=2016-11-31 00:00:00`. **the where condition based on your date and time format.**

Comment: @Karthi  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given  but given while ($row = mysqli_result($result)) is says Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result()  and prints out Money made for this month is 0 , there is a value greater than 0 in the table

Comment: @Blue_Jay i think query has syntax error . plz check it use this code `if (!$query) {
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error();
        exit;
    }`

Comment: @Karthi how can i run that sql query because when  i echo $query from $query = "select SUM(Money) from tab_name where Joined<='2016-11-01 00:00:00' and Joined>=2016-11-31 00:00:00";  .Php  assumes that is a string

Comment: okay now u get out or not

Comment: @Karthi not yet , i wanted to know how i can run mysql query directly to a webpage without assigning it to a variable like $query. is there a way ?

Comment: oh okay just use `mysqli_query("your query goes here")`. but we need variable to store it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Prize` is a numerical value, you could do something like the following.

```
$month = 'January';

$month_start = strtotime("first day of {$month}");
$month_end = strtotime("last day of {$month}");

$query = "SELECT SUM(`Prize`) FROM `equipments` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Joined`) >= {$month_start} AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Joined`) <= {$month_end}";
```

Comment: OP expecting to get sum of data from particular month. but u miss that .

Comment: @Jayme Brereton  i wanted  results  for  specific data not the whole total

Comment: @JaymeBrereton your approach gives me an error . it says there is an unexpected $result

Comment: you missed the semicolon at the end of the $query line

Comment: @JaymeBrereton there is an error . mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Mind doing `var_dump($result);` before your while loop?